# Cannot deselect previous programmatically selected row in tableview after another selection

Tags: swift3, tableview, row, deselect

I am using both in cellForRowAt and exact in the same function that initialize the tableview this code:

```
cell.accessoryType = selectedOption == indexPath.row ? .checkmark : .none
```

and my tableview got checkmark automatically for selectedOption, but when I select another option the checkmark that I set earlier doesn't disapear and after that there are 2 checkmarks on the table with setted allowsMultipleSelection to false. Why this is happening and why my first checkmark doesn't hide after my selection ?

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
     if let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) {
                cell.accessoryType = .checkmark
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think if you reload your tableview it will works, your code is fine, just reload your table in didselect.

Comment: I reload it betfore and after selection I am receiving 2 checkmarks if its before, if its after everytime selection is wrong.

Comment: @ShivamPokhriyal why not? Wherever your tableview need update you can call reloadData. It doesn’t matter whether it is in didSelect or any other action.

Comment: Wouldn't it cause any issue with performance. Just the idea that you are reloading the entire tableview for every click on tableview cell. And if there are 100 cells of different types I guess this might create some performance issue

Comment: @ShivamPokhriyal Well in that case you should reload the needed cell, thats all..

Comment: The idea of reloading itself is wrong in my opinion. There should be some better way to achieve this!

Comment: @ShivamPokhriyal May be, if you find something then definitely share. It help others. Thank you